# Entity Framework : how to create double relationship (1-1 and many-1) with same objects

Tags: database, entity-framework, mapping, relationships, fluent-entity-framework

I have two class :

```
class Sub
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime ValidDate { get; set; }
    public Guid MasterId { get; set; }
    public Master Master { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
class Master
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int Data { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Sub> Subs { get; set; }
    public Sub MainSub { get; set; }
}
```

To be simple, a master have a main sub to define it, and can have 0 or more "secondary" subs.
I've tried to do mapping this way

```
var mBuilder = modelBuilder.Entity<Master>();
mBuilder.HasMany(m => m.Subs).WithOne(m => m.Master).HasForeignKey(m => m.MasterId);
mBuilder.HasOne(m => m.MainSub).WithOne(m => m.Master);
```

but I have an exception as expected ("Master cannot participate in two relationships"). I don't want to change my model cause it fits what I need, how can I perform such a mapping to do so ?

Comment: Think of how you would model this in SQL. Can't be done with one FK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot map this relationship. Every relationship has 2 endpoints and one complex property in your class cannot be the endpoint for 2 relationships.

I would create a **`bool? IsMainSub`** property in my **`Sub`** class and also create a unique key constraint for **`MasterId`** and **`IsMainSub`** in my **`Sub`** class. This would ensure that a `Master` record cannot have 2 main `Sub` records.

**UPDATE** - I know this doesn't look perfect, the `IsMainSub` property would only allow the values `true` and `null` since setting the value `false` would trigger the unique constraint violation. This is logic you can add to your property setter to take any `false` value and convert it to null.

For what I can recall, you can create a unique key constraint that allows `null` value for some columns without violating the constraint. I would double check this.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. In fact, I would rather keep my MainSub a pure in memory notion, extract it from collection when accessing and keep a single relationship. It's weaker cause I cannot assert, from a db perspective, that I have a mainSub defined, but it's enough ok. If I had to implement the solution, your's seems to be the proper one, so I'll mark it as answer